# Appending integers from a list to each row to a new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of integers `x` and I am trying to create a new column to an existing dataframe that has each of the `x[0] ... x[1345]` in the appropriate place.

This is what I did:

```
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    df['Paystrings'] = x[i]
    i = i + 1
df.head()
```

But I only get this:

[image]

Which is just the last element of `x`

Comment: You overwrite `df['Paystrings']` in each iteration. What's your desired output? Do you want to create 1346 _new_ columns?

Comment: That's because you are redefining the column with the value `x[i]`. So at the end of the loop, that will be `x[-1]` for the whole column

Comment: Yes because df['Paystrings'] = x[i] sets the whole column to the value x[i]

Comment: @pault I want to create a new column called Paystring, then for each row in that coilumn put x[0] in the first row x[1] in the second etc... does that make sense?'

Comment: I'd probably wrap `x` in a `Series` to stick into the Dataframe

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Here is a dupe: [Add column in dataframe from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666919/add-column-in-dataframe-from-list/38490727)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a index explizit set in the creation you can do this:

```
df['Paystrings'] = pd.Series(x)
```

Elsewise you can reset the index, then all elements have the number like they are sorted in this moment.

```
df.reset_index()
```