# Replacing series values pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this following dataframe:

[image]

And i have this following list:

[image]

and i want to replace the series value of team_stat['First Half']['W'] to the list value of first_half_win_result

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add column in dataframe from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666919/add-column-in-dataframe-from-list)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it would convert list to `series` for `pandas`

```
team_stat['First Half']['W'] = pd.Series(first_half_win_result)
```

Comment: no errors, after executing the code, the dataframe is still the same no changes are there

Comment: please upload your code to google colab and let me have a look there

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fDnlPNPLNjdVEDxF2mN8G0_79-Cx6p26

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/177acsnCzZCB6zfMTBp7Mju-RsYBG-WVO

Comment: CSV? what's the name of the file? I will download it

Comment: https://github.com/Slothfulwave612/La_Liga_2018_19  laliga_2018_19.csv

Answer (score 1):

well i find the solution:

```
   team_stat = team_stat.transpose()
   team_stat.loc['First Half', 'W'] = first_half_win_result
   team_stat = team_stat.transpose()
```