# Pandas DataFrame - Fill NaNs of columns based on values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a wide data frame with several years:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index([29925, 223725, 280165, 813285, 956765], name='ID'),
                  columns=pd.Index([1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, '2010-2012'], name='Year'),
                  data = np.array([[np.NaN, np.NaN, 16, 17, 18, 19, np.NaN],
                                   [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, np.NaN],
                                   [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 16, 17, 31],
                                   [np.NaN, 22, 23, 24, np.NaN, 26, np.NaN],
                                   [36, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 55]]))

Year     1991  1992  1993  1994  1995  1996  2010-2012
ID                                                    
29925     NaN   NaN  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0        NaN
223725   16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  21.0        NaN
280165    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  16.0  17.0       31.0
813285    NaN  22.0  23.0  24.0   NaN  26.0        NaN
956765   36.0  36.0  37.0  38.0  39.0  40.0       55.0
```

The values in each row are the age of each person, with each holding a unique ID. I want to fill the `NaN` of this data frame in each year of every row, based on the existing age values in each row.

For example, ID `29925` is 16 in `1993`, we know they are 15 in `1992` and 14 in `1991`, therefore we want to replace the `NaN` for `29925` in the columns `1992` and `1991`. Similarly, I want to replace the `NaN` in the column`2010-2012` based on the existing age values for `29925`. Let's assume that `29925` is 15 years older from `1996` in the `2010-2012` column. What is the fastest way to do this for the whole data frame - i.e for all IDs?

Comment: last line first 36 is 35, yepp? There shouldn't be two 36s...

Comment: Yeah, can you definitely explain that last row? If there's a possibility that your data are messy such that age doesn't always increase by 1 year to year (or only by 14 from 1996- 2010-2012 instead of 15) how do you want to resolve such cases? In that case I could imagine you might have gaps like `35 NaN 36` and it becomes impossible to know whether that `NaN` should become 35 or 36...

Comment: Hi thank you both for the replies, we can argue it is unknown whether the last line should be 35 or 36. The data is from a hypothetical survey and that person could have been 36 time they responded to the survey in both 1991 and 1992, for example they responded in Dec-1991 and again in Jan-1992, their birthday is in June. As for the cases with the other ```NaNs```, it should be filled according to a general rule of +1 or -1 according to the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

```
# imports we need later
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

---

This is a not a particularly efficient method but it works. I'll leave out your last column, to make things more systematic.

The `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index([29925, 223725, 280165, 813285, 956765], name='ID'),
                  columns=pd.Index([1992, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996], name='Year'),
                  data = np.array([[np.NaN, np.NaN, 16, 17, 18, 19],
                                   [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
                                   [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 16, 17],
                                   [np.NaN, 22, 23, 24, np.NaN, 26],
                                   [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]))
```

[image]

Calculate date of birth for everyone:

```
dob=[]
for irow, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    dob.append(np.asarray([int(each) for each in df.columns]) - np.asarray(df.iloc[irow,:]))
```

*or*, if you are into list [comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520):

```
dob = [np.asarray([int(each) for each in df.columns]) - np.asarray(df.iloc[irow,:]) for irow, row in enumerate(df.iterrows())]
```

Now `dob` is like this:

```
[array([  nan,   nan, 1977., 1977., 1977., 1977.]),
 array([1976., 1975., 1975., 1975., 1975., 1975.]),
 array([  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan, 1979., 1979.]),
 array([  nan, 1970., 1970., 1970.,   nan, 1970.]),
 array([1956., 1956., 1956., 1956., 1956., 1956.])]
```

Make a simpler dob list using [np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), [remove nans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620982/8565438):

```
dob_filtered=[np.unique(each[~np.isnan(each)])[0] for each in dob]
```

`dob_filtered` now looks like this:

```
[1977.0, 1975.0, 1979.0, 1970.0, 1956.0]
```

[Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38490727/8565438) this list to dataframe:

```
df['dob']=dob_filtered
```

Fill in the `NaN`s of the `df` using the `dob` column:

```
for irow, row in enumerate(df.index):
    for icol, col in enumerate(df.columns[:-2]):
        df.loc[row,col] = col - df['dob'][row]
```

[Delete](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the `dob` column (just to obtain the original columns only, otherwise not important):

```
df.drop(['dob'],axis=1)
```

Obtaining:

```
Year    1992    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996
ID                      
29925   15.0    15.0    16.0    17.0    18.0    19.0
223725  17.0    17.0    18.0    19.0    20.0    21.0
280165  13.0    13.0    14.0    15.0    16.0    17.0
813285  22.0    22.0    23.0    24.0    25.0    26.0
956765  36.0    36.0    37.0    38.0    39.0    40.0
```

ie

[image]

Comment: I had been thinking about this for so long and honestly creating a DataFrame of the birth year really is the key to doing this efficiently. You can actually get around a lot of the iterations once you have `dob` and fffil and bffill it.

Comment: I found the problem intriguing as well; if you can make it more efficient by getting around the iterations, I am interested!

Comment: (Feel free to edit my answer or add your own using parts of mine)

Comment: dob is the key... if df has many rows it might be faster to build the whole df from scratch: `df_new = pd.DataFrame([[col - dob for col in df.columns[:-2]] for dob in df['dob'], index=df.index, columns=df.columns[:-2])` ...then add 2010-2012 unchanged