# Adding a new column to DataFrame with different values in different row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a DataFrame `df` which has `50` columns in it and it has 28800 rows. I want to add a new column `col_new` which will have value `0`  in every rows from `2880 to 5760` ,`12960 to 15840` and `23040 to 25920`. And all other rows will have value `1`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe what you are looking for is actually answered here: [Add column in dataframe from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666919/add-column-in-dataframe-from-list)

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(len(df)) # 50
df['new_col'] = mylist
print(len(df)) # 51
```

Alternatively, you could set the value of a slice of the list like so:

```
data['new_col'] = 1
data.loc[2880:5760, 'new_col'] = 0
data.loc[12960:15840, 'new_col'] = 0
data.loc[23040:25920, 'new_col'] = 0
```

Comment: if index starts in 0, that would change from row 2881th instead of 2880th, if index starts in one that would be ok.

Comment: I'm sure OP can figure this out

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in range(28800)])
df["new_col"] = 1
zeros_bool = [(
    (i>=(2880-1) and i<5760) or (i>=(12960-1) and i<15840) or (i>=(23040-1) and i<25920)
) for i in range(28800)]
df.loc[zeros_bool,"new_col"] = 0
```