# Creating a df from a list created from another df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a list into a dataframe, but this list was created by another dataframme, so it has index without header in it, and I'm trying to convert it into another df and failing.

id_range = [100,200,300,400,400]

summary
df : a normal df with an index

```
    Name ID 
0   Paul    100  
1   Lauren  200  
2   Beth    300 
3   Chris   400  
4   Andy    500
```

list : the df converted into a list with a new column added(it has index without header\column name)

```
    Name Surname ID 
0   Paul Logan 100  
1   Lauren Text 200  
2   Beth Cameron 300 
3   Chris Lenon 400  
4   Andy Steve 500
```

new_df : what im trying to do, convert the list into this new_df to make another operation using a df

could you guys help me?

I tried

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

but this doesnt give me everything, just one row

Comment: Please edit your question to include example data following the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Without data, nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: share your `list`. Check-https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [Add column in dataframe from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666919/add-column-in-dataframe-from-list)

Comment: If it's possible, can you also post your desired output?

Comment: a new df from the mentioned list, simple as that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> list : the df converted into a list with a new column added(it has index without header\column name)

Considering `list` should be as below after conversion of `df` to `list` and added `surname` in `list`.

USE `df_new = pd.DataFrame(list[1:],columns=list[0])` to get `df_new`, first element in `list` will act as `Column name` in `df_new`

```
import pandas as pd
  
list =  [['Name','Surname','ID'],['Paul', 'Logan', 100],['Louren','Text',200],["Beth","Camron",300],["Chris","Lenon",400],["Andy","Steve",500]] 
df_new = pd.DataFrame(list[1:],columns=list[0])
df_new
```

Output-

```
    Name    Surname ID
0   Paul    Logan   100
1   Louren  Text    200
2   Beth    Camron  300
3   Chris   Lenon   400
4   Andy    Steve   500
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried that, but, look what I got:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (12, 1)

and the command I tried was :
df_final = pd.DataFrame(list_dados[1:],columns=list_dados[0])

Comment: @gfernandes then your `list` is not similar with the `list` I am using in the answer, you will require `list` to be as above to work