# Append a new column list of values in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
+-----------+---+
|       Name|Age|
+-----------+---+
|Emma Larter| 34|
| Mia Junior| 59|
|Sophia Depp| 32|
|James Smith| 40|
+-----------+---+
```

I have a spark dataframe as above. I want to append a column to the dataframe using below list:

```py
Salary = [35000, 24000, 55000, 40000]
```

How to do it in simple way using spark?

I can do this with pandas, but not spark.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666919/add-column-in-dataframe-from-list

Answer (score 3):

Using `Pyspark` use `zipWithIndex` function to generate the index column and use it join.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df= spark.createDataFrame([('Emma Larter',34),('Mia Junior',59),('Sophia',32),('James',40)],['Name','Age'])
df_ind = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd.zipWithIndex(),['val','ind'])
Salary = [35000, 24000, 55000, 40000]
df_salary = spark.createDataFrame(spark.createDataFrame(Salary, IntegerType()).rdd.zipWithIndex(),['val1','ind'])
df_ind.join(df_salary,['ind']).select("val.*","val1.*").drop('ind').show()

#+-----------+---+-----+
#|       Name|Age|value|
#+-----------+---+-----+
#|Emma Larter| 34|35000|
#| Mia Junior| 59|24000|
#|     Sophia| 32|55000|
#|      James| 40|40000|
#+-----------+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily convert your pyspark dataframe into `Pandas` using [toPandas()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html) method and then append the new column to it

```
from pyspark.shell import spark

data = [("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 30), ("Charlie", 35)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "age"])

new_pandas_df = df.toPandas()
new_pandas_df['gender'] = ['M', 'F', 'M']

print(new_pandas_df)
```

Output:
[image]

Please note i've used some test dataframe in my answer, but please change it according to yours. Also `pandas` has it own downfall since it does all the processing in memory, so consider this when you're doing it for a larger dataset.